# what is the best way to deliver 50 MB of json data from google storage to client side indexeddb

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm fetching a [json file](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/konstant-ccbcc.appspot.com/o/TestCatalog.json?alt=media&token=fd5a5aa7-cbd4-4277-8f80-fc8bacbdf7b3)of about 45MB from Google Storage, the code works and display the file content in firebase function log dashboard but the content is not delivered to client side.

The code works for a smaller size file but not this large size. I have increased allocated memory to 2GiB and timeout to 240s to give it enough memory and run time before timing out. However none of this seems to work for the large file. I just want to deliver the content to the client side so that I save the content to indexeddb.

Here is my code

```
exports.updateProductCatalogue = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
 
const filename = data.filename;
console.log(filename)


const remoteFile = bucket.file(filename);

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let buffer = '';

  remoteFile.createReadStream()
   
  .on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    reject(err);
  })
  .on('data', function(response) {
    
    buffer += response;
     
    console.log(buffer);
  })
  .on('end', function() {

    console.log("FINISHED!!")
    
    resolve(buffer);
  })
 
})});
```

and I call the function from client side

```js
function getUpdatedCatalogue(){
  var getStorageData = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('updateProductCatalogue');
  var callData = {
    "filename":"TestCatalog.json"
   }
  getStorageData(callData).then(function(result){
  
    console.log(result)
    
    
    $.each(result["data"], function( index, value ){
      console.log(index)
      
    });

  }).catch(function(error){
    console.log(error)

  })
}
```

what is the best way to delivery this content quickly to the client side so that I save them to indexeddb?

I am opened to other options to solve this outside of Google Cloud

Comment: Google Cloud Functions is a requirement or you can switch to another serverless service, like Cloud Run?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Google Cloud is not a requirement. I am opened to other options.

Answer (score 1):

The limit for both upload and download payloads in Cloud Functions 10MB.  You're exceeding that.  There are no workarounds.

Instead, you could deliver a link to the client so it can download directly from Cloud Storage.

Comment: yes, i thought of downloading and loading the json file locally but I haven't found a way to locally load json file in javascript.